# Non exhaustive pattern in function in GHCi

Tags: function, haskell, multiline, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

I want to make a function that displays the last element of a list. 
This is my code:

```
ghci> let myLast :: [a] -> a
ghci> let myLast [] = error 
ghci> let myLast [x] = x
ghci> let myLast (x:xs) = myLast xs
```

And I get the following error:

> ```
> ***Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLast
> ```

I understood that you get this error when you're missing a case, but I think I have included all the possibilities. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a `let` in each line, each definition will make a *new* function named `myLast`, shadowing all the previous definitions. So what you end up with is equivalent to

> GHCi> let myLast (x:xs) = myLast xs

alone.

What you probably want is to make a haskell file, say `MyLast.hs`, containing

```
module MyLast where

myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast [] = error 
myLast [x] = x
myLast (x:xs) = myLast xs
```

you can then load that file into GHCi with `ghci MyLast.hs`.

The keyword `let` is only needed when you're already in GHCi (or, in some monad like `IO`, or in another function) and want to make a *local definition*. But then you must only use the `let` once, e.g.

> GHCi> let myLast :: [a]->a; myLast [] = error; myLast [x] = x; myLast (x:xs) = myLast xs

or

```
twiceLast :: [Int] -> [Int]
twiceLast = let myLast [] = error 
                myLast [x] = x
                myLast (x:xs) = myLast xs
            in \xs -> 2 * last xs
```

which I would, however, prefer to write as

```
twiceLast = (2*) . myLast
 where myLast [] = error 
       myLast [x] = x
       myLast (x:xs) = myLast xs
```

Answer (score 3):

In ghci each use of `let` introduces a new definition, so you are redefining your function multiple times instead of adding cases.

Two alternatives:

- place the definition in a file and load it with the `:r` command
- use `:{ ... :}` to enter multiple lines:

E.g.:

```
*Main> :{
*Main| let foo [] = True
*Main|     foo _ = False
*Main| :}
*Main>
```