# Non-exhaustive patterns in function defined in GHCi

Tags: haskell, exception, ghci

I'm trying to write a sieve of Eratosthenes function that gives a user all Primes from 2 to their upper Limit. So I've written this code:

```
main = do
putStrLn "Upper Limit"
g <- readLn
let sieve [] = []
let sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x | x <- xs, x `mod` p /= 0]
let primes = sieve [2..g]
print primes
```

The code compiles and is giving me the right solution but I'm getting this exception at the end of the solution:

> Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function sieve

So I've checked what patterns aren't matched.

```
warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `sieve': Patterns not matched: (_:_)

warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `sieve': Patterns not matched: []
```

Which I don't understand since I've given `let sieve [] = []`
And I thought _ in Haskell means any variable so what does the pattern `(_:_)` mean?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it do this if you write them as functions outside of main?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non exhaustive pattern in function in GHCi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738392/non-exhaustive-pattern-in-function-in-ghci)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you **define `sieve` in two separate `let` statements**. As a result the Haskell compiler thinks that you define **two separate `sieve` functions**. Therefore the first `sieve` lacks a `(_:_)` pattern and the latter the `[]` pattern.

If you later use `sieve`, the Haskell compiler will link to the closest one, so the latter (as a result a call to `sieve`) in `let primes = sieve [2..g]` will only know of the *second* `sieve` definition (and will thus error on the end of the list).

You can solve this by using the following `let` statement:

```
let { sieve [] = [] ; sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x | x <- xs, x `mod` p /= 0] }
```

Comment: You can also indent both parts of the definition to the same level after `let`.